# Does the use of macro in LaTeX slow down the compilation process?

Tags: macros

Use of macro eases document preparation, further modification, uniformity maintenance, just to name a few of the enormous benefits we enjoy.

But does the use of a macro slow down the compilation process?

How does LaTeX handle the macros? In place replacements?

Comment: Usually no, but it depends on what the macro is doing, and other stuff

Comment: Macros that do writing stuff to files are slowing the down the process, but this depends on the amount of content to be written of course. (And this is basically not the fault of TeX macros but rather an OS issue then)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am asking this, since as a compiler teacher I know that there are two concepts in programming languages, macro (in place replacements) and functions (compiled then linked). We call LaTeX macros macros, but they look more like functions. But what happens during compilation?

Comment: @daleif Why *usually* no? Why no, and when yes, why?

Comment: It naturally depends on the macro.

Comment: The whole of  `LaTeX` is macros. Only `TeX` has primitives.

Comment: @Masroor imagine a macro that never ends. most macros that you will use are simple substitution macros there you will not see any difference when compiling.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try the following input file `expansion.tex`:

```
\def\1{\empty\empty\empty\empty\empty\empty\empty\empty\empty\empty}
\def\2{\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1\1}
\def\3{\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2\2}
\def\4{\3\3\3\3\3\3\3\3\3\3}
\def\5{\4\4\4\4\4\4\4\4\4\4}
\def\6{\5\5\5\5\5\5\5\5\5\5}
\def\7{\6\6\6\6\6\6\6\6\6\6}
\def\8{\7\7\7\7\7\7\7\7\7\7}
\def\9{\8\8\8\8\8\8\8\8\8\8}
\def\0{\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9\9}

\do

\bye
```

and time the compilation with

```
time tex '\def\do{\7}\input expansion'
```

I get

```
real    0m0.532s
user    0m0.504s
sys     0m0.012s
```

You can easily figure out the number of macro expansions required. With `\8` in place of `\7` I get

```
real    0m4.340s
user    0m4.126s
sys     0m0.017s
```

Yes, it's of course an exponential growth; don't try with `\0` `;-)` With `\6` I get

```
real    0m0.157s
user    0m0.142s
sys     0m0.012s
```

which shows that compiling a reasonable document is not slowed down by using macros.

Macros are, well, macros: when expansion of a macro is required, TeX does in place replacement of the macro with the tokens resulting from the replacement text currently stored in memory.

Answer (score 5):

With ConTeXt, it is possible to get more fine-grained information about typesetting time. The macro is `\testfeature`

```
\testfeature{n}{....}
```

will execute the second argument `n` times and report the execution time on the terminal. Let's compare simple macro expansion:

```
\def\ABC{ABC}
\starttext
\testfeature{100000}{ABC}
\testfeature{100000}{\ABC}
\stoptext
```

This gives:

```
system          > starting feature test

\wait =
system          > 100000 feature tests done (0.060s)

\wait =
system          > starting feature test

\wait =
system          > 100000 feature tests done (0.066s)

\wait =
```

So, typesetting `ABC` `10^6` times took `0.060s` while typesetting `\ABC` `10^6` times took `0.066s`. So, the difference is `6ms` for `10^6` or **6 nano seconds per expansion**! I wouldn't worry about the speed of macro expansion :-)